# Python Pandas Series to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a Series returned from a groupby function:

```
In  [1]: IC
Out [1]:
date
2017-01-01    [1, 2, 3]
2017-01-02    [1, 2, 3]
2017-01-03    [1, 2, 3]
```

How do I transform it to a dataframe like this:

```
In  [2]: IC_df
Out [2]:
date         a1    a2    a3
2017-01-01    1     2     3
2017-01-02    1     2     3
2017-01-03    1     2     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a `pd.Series` in your groupby function instead of a list.